# How I get $key when I using ngFor using angularfire2?

Tags: json, firebase, angularfire

I have some question, example I have a json file:

```
{
  "items" : {
    "khanh" : {
      "name":"2017 shirt",
      "size":["S","M","L"],
      "image":"http://placehold.it/650x450",
      "likes":0,
      "price":123
    },
    "-KdleehAQm0HgVFYdkUo" : {
      "name":"2017 shirt",
      "size":["S","M","L"],
      "image":"http://placehold.it/650x450",
      "likes":0,
      "price":123
    },
    "-Kdlg3AqKNTnbhjAVT8h" : {
      "name":"2017 shirt",
      "size":["S","M","L"],
      "image":"http://placehold.it/650x450",
      "likes":0,
      "price":123
    }
  }
}
```

I have a button that update how many likes. But I have a problem. I don't know how to get the "key". Example:"khanh","-KdleehAQm0HgVFYdkUo"

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md#meta-fields-on-the-object

Comment: Elements in a `FirebaseListObservable` have a `$key` property.

Comment: I know that but how to get $key of each object ?

Comment: Cartant thanks u i will try it

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

**Component**:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

dbcomplextest: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

constructor(afDB: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.dbcomplextest = afDB.list('/complex/');
}
```

**View**:

```
<span *ngFor="let value of dbcomplextest | async">
    {{ value.$key }} - {{ value.$value }}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version `>=4.6.0`, you have to use `snapshotChanges().map()` to store the key.

```
   this.itemsRef = db.list('messages');
// Use snapshotChanges().map() to store the key
this.items = this.itemsRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
  return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
});
```

Then now you can be able to get it from your view list using `.key`